# Page 404 NoT Found Even the Tomcat is not showing any error

Tags: struts

I am trying to run this simple example on eclipse .As i run the server it is not showing any error .But in the browser it is showing 404 error page not found. I don't understand what is the error.I have used all the Jars in my WEB-INF/Lib folder too.

THE CODE SNIPPET is below:

**CLASS HELLOWORLDACTION**

```
     package com.action;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
        import org.apache.struts.action.Action;
        import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
        import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
        import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

        import com.form.HelloWorldForm;
        public class HelloWorldAction extends Action{

            public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping,ActionForm form,
                    HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

                HelloWorldForm helloWorldForm = (HelloWorldForm) form;
                helloWorldForm.setMessage("Hello World! Struts");
                return mapping.findForward("success");}

        }
```

**CLASS HelloWorldForm**

```
package com.form;

     import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;

     public class HelloWorldForm extends ActionForm{

     String message;

   public String getMessage() {
   return message;
  }
     public void setMessage(String message) {
   this.message = message;
  }

 }
```

**Struts-config.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC 
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN" 
    "http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">

    <struts-config>

        <form-beans>
            <form-bean name="helloWorldForm" 
                type="com.form.HelloWorldForm"/>
        </form-beans>

        <action-mappings>
            <action path="/helloWorld"
                type="com.action.HelloWorldAction"
                name="helloWorldForm">
                <forward name="success" path="/HelloWorld.jsp"/>
                </action>
        </action-mappings>

    </struts-config>
```

**Web.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
            <display-name>Maven Struts Examples</display-name> 
          <servlet>
            <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>
                org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet
            </servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>config</param-name>
                <param-value>
                 /WEB-INF/struts-config.xml
                </param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
          </servlet>

          <servlet-mapping>
               <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
               <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
          </servlet-mapping>

        </web-app>
```

**HelloWorld.jsp**

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean"%>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1><bean:write name="helloWorldForm" property="message" />
    </h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What is the URL you are trying to hit?

Comment: Your url should be something like http://localhost:8080/webapps/<app name>/page.do

Comment: What do you mean by "all the jars"?

Comment: The error is the page is not found.

Comment: @jason                                                                i am trying to send the message string from the servlet to the jsp.As i am new to struts please bear with me.My url is localhost:8080/servletname.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using the wrong url. Tomcat generally has a folder called `webapps` for applications that are deployed on that server. To figure out the configuration, in Eclipse, open up the `Server` tab, find your Tomcat server and double-click on it.

It should bring up a properties pane with two tabs at the bottom `Overview` and `Modules`. Click on `Modules` and you should see the path to your app. For me, it's in the form of: `/webapps/<project name>`

Your full url would be `localhost:8080/webapps/<project name>/anystringhere.do` since you map anything in your app (`localhost:8080/webapps/<project name>/`) that ends in `.do` to the action servlet.